# PHP While loop putting Br tag in it

Tags: php

I'm new in php programming. Just learning from different sources, I made a small code that that if a value <= to value ---- then multiply it with 5. It works but I want to put 
 tag in it to break each multiplied value to the next line, but I can't. The second thing that I'm going with is put a "," after multiplying value but it doesn't work. Can any one help? My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$a = 0;
   while ($a <= 400){
       echo $a . ", " * 5 ; 
$a++ ;
}echo "<br/> Count: {$a}";
?>
```

Comment: if you can echo a comma you c an echo a `<br>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but I'm pretty sure this is what you want:

```
<?php
$a = 0;
while ($a <= 400){
    echo ($a * 5) . ",<br/>"; // multiply, echo, add break
    $a++;
}
echo "<br/> Count: {$a}";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution that takes care of the **trailing** comma as well is:

```
$a = 0;
while(1) {
    echo ($a * 5);
    if(++$a <= 400) {
        echo ", ";   
    } else {
        break;    
    };
}
echo "<br/> Count: {$a}";
```

**Output:**

> 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, ... [snip] ... 1900, 1905, 1910, 1915, 1920, 1925, 1930, 1935, 1940, 1945, 1950, 1955, 1960, 1965, 1970, 1975, 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000
>  Count: 401

Comment: Drakes you made a so complex coding make your coding simple every time in this simple output no need of ( if statement) that your using.;

Comment: It takes care of the **trailing** comma left by other answers.

Comment: ya its take  control of comma but you made it complex as a beginner @Drakes make your program more simple so it will help you alot. im not expert like you but its my thinking i don't know its write or wrong but i thing like this.  sorry for bad english

Comment: Something to chew on and learn more cool things about PHP with ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Ed Cottrell, or also:

```
<?php
$a = 0;
while ($a <= 400) {
    echo $a . " * 5 = " . ($a*5) . "<br />" ; // e.g: 12 * 5 = 60
    $a++ ;
}
echo "<br/> Count: {$a}";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = 0;
   while ($a <= 400){
       echo $a * 5 ; 
$a++ ;
}echo "<br/> Count: {$a}";
?>
```

If you need to add `,` for every value then use the following,

```
<?php
$a = 0;
   while ($a <= 400){
       echo $a*5.", "; 
$a++ ;
}echo "<br/> Count: {$a}";
?>
```

Or display every value in new line use the following code,

```
<?php
$a = 0;
   while ($a <= 400){
       echo $a*5."\n"; 
$a++ ;
}echo "<br/> Count: {$a}";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @EdCottrell has posted, you could simply add the values to an array and [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) them:

```
$a = 0;
$data = array();
while ($a <= 400){
    $data[] = ($a * 5); 
    $a++;
}
// print it
echo implode(", ", $data);
echo "\n\n Count: {$a}";
```

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#sqksNSHXX)